# Strange behavior while using display inline-block ...why?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <p>normal</p>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <p>normal</p>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <p>normal</p>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <p>Why does this div stays at the top</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    width:120px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jezVt/

I have four divs aligned next to each other using inline-block. When I enter text inside the div using p tag, the div with two lines stays at the top while the other three divs(has just one line text) are aligned properly.

Help please..

Comment: add  float:left; in .menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that just like every inline element, your `.menu` elements have the default value `baseline` for their `vertical-align` property. This means that when the browser calculates layout for the `.menu` elements that appear side-by-side, each element is positioned so that *the baseline of their contents is vertically aligned with that of the others*.

In this specific case, this means that the baseline of last line of text in each `.menu` is aligned with that of the others. You will notice that by adding more text and making it to occupy three or more lines, the element that contains this text is going to be "pulled upwards" more and more in relation to the others.

Finally, as everyone has said using `vertical-align: top` lets the browser know that you want the divs to be aligned with respect to the *top* of their content, which produces the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

add you code `vertical-align:top;` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jezVt/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
write vertical-align:top; in css:http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/jezVt/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

From my first look, is that you have to much text in the fourth column.

But use "vertical-align: top;" as the two previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make divs as inline-block. When div is a block level element you can use that property itself.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/jezVt/12/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try:

```
.menu{
    width:120px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```